# Python merge two lists into tuple of two tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to merge two lists into a tuple of two tuples

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 = ['one','two','three','four','five']
```

desired output:

```
tup_of_2_tups = ((1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three'),
                 (4,'four'),(5,'five'))
```

Comment: `tuple(zip(lst1,lst2))`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

credit to @WillemVanOnsem:

```
output = tuple(zip(lst1,lst2))
```